# Uninstall a Jekyll-Bootstrap theme

Tags: rake, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I installed several Jekyll-Bootstrap themes using rake as described [here](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-theming.html).

```
rake theme:install git="https://github.com/jekyllbootstrap/theme-the-program.git"
```

How do I uninstall the themes I don't want? Do I need to manually delete all the associated files?

Comment: You can safely remove useless themes folders from `_inclures/themes`.

Comment: Thanks. There are also theme-specific files in assets/themes. Am I missing any other ones?

Comment: I've missed `assets/themes`. No more folder to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure this goes down as answered, I want to put down what [David Jacquel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548376/david-jacquel) said in [his comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973078/uninstall-a-jekyll-bootstrap-theme#comment51857222_31973078):

File folders for themes are stored in `_includes/themes` and `assets/themes`.
Delete these and your unwanted themes will be gone.

A second option for removal, which I'm not positive about, is to run the reverse of what you did to install, in your case: `rake theme:uninstall git="https://github.com/jekyllbootstrap/theme-the-program.git"`. For others, it might be `gem uninstall [theme-gem-name]` if you installed the theme that way.